# couldn't load site name in html template

Tags: theming

```
<?php print $site_name; ?>
```

Why I couldn't perform the above code in 'html.tpl.php'. This works find in page template. Please suggest how to load this in html template

Answer (score 0):

There's no `$site_name` variable added to [html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7), but you can add it yourself quite easily with a preprocess hook:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['site_name'] = variable_get('site_name', 'Default');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Clive. 
Site name the name of value entered in "admin/config/system/site-information"

    <?php print $site_name; ?>